# How to modify the Layout params of a child in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android

Anyone help me to modify the layout params of a child in a ListView in Android.Please give some code snippets if you can.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://androidguys.com/?p=633) [is](http://androidguys.com/?p=635) [a](http://androidguys.com/?p=636) [long](http://androidguys.com/?p=639) [series](http://androidguys.com/?p=642) [of](http://androidguys.com/?p=644) [blog](http://androidguys.com/?p=659) posts that I found really useful when I started to create my first custom ListView.

**NOTE:** every word is a separate link ;)

Comment: A sample code would be nice, its easier than scouring trough six links.

Answer (score 5):

The childs need the LayoutParams from the parent so:

**First - The inflater:**

```
convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main_menu,parent,false);
```

Look the 2 and 3 parameter.

**Second - The LayoutParams:**

The ListView LayoutParams not appear in eclipse intellisense!
Try this:

```
ListView.LayoutParams params = new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own Adapter class and overwrite the getView method. The getView method is called for each position in the list.

You'll have to overwrite some other methods too as given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

You can create custom views and return them from the getView method. Remember to use the older view passed down to the method if its possible for optimum memory usage